# Powershell script to enable 'IIS Management Scripts and Tools'

Tags: powershell, windows-7, build-automation

After looking around (for not terribly long I have to admit) I wonder if anyone can point me to a Powershell script that checks if 'IIS Management Scripts and Tools' is enabled and if its not then it enables it like you would from Add Windows features.

I checked poshcode.org and powershell.com and couldnt find one

I never touched Powershell before and I m trying to use this script to run as part of deployment automation

Cheers

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Would that be for Windows 2008 or Windows Server 2008 R2?

Server 2008R2:

-To query:

```
PS> get-windowsfeature|where{$_.name -eq "Web-Scripting-Tools"}

Display Name                                            Name
------------                                            ----
        [X] IIS Management Scripts and Tools            Web-Scripting-Tools
```

The "[X]" indicates it is installed.

-To add:

```
PS> get-windowsfeature|where{$_.name -eq "Web-Scripting-Tools"}|add-windowsfeature
```

If you're asking about Server 2008, then you'll have to parse the output from servermanagercmd.exe, which will be a bit tougher, but not impossible.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think powershell is a good choice for automated installation because first you have to install powershell (unless this is windows 2008 R2) and then you have to enable script execution before your scripts will run.

Instead us pkgmgr or ocsetup which can be run from a regular cmd.exe console.
This should work for IIS 7 (Windows 2008)

```
start /w pkgmgr /iu:IIS-WebServerManagementTools;IIS-ManagementConsole;
start /w pkgmgr /iu:IIS-ManagementScriptingTools;IIS-ManagementService;
start /w pkgmgr /iu:IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility;IIS-Metabase;
```

If you are really determined to use powershell this will install it on Windows 2008

```
start /w pkgmgr /iu:MicrosoftWindowsPowerShell
```

Keep in mind that this installs the Windows 2008 OS "Feature" and so you will get PowerShell version 1.0 not PowerShell version 2.0.

This article explains how to get PowerShell v 2 for your OS (2008 and earlier)
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929

Comment: I know this is old advise by Mark, but today, to do server administration without Powershell is (almost) not viable. On a servers, GUI is on the way out along with 'local administration': Small footprint and remote admin via Powershell.